# rspec what is the difference between be nil and be_nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I am using rspec and for asserts like

```
student.name should be nil
student.name should be_nil
```

Both seem to work. is there a difference between using `be nil` an `be_nil` ???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no difference really, except `be nil` gets defined on the fly, and `be_nil` has been specifically programmed by rspec.

when you say `should.be something`, rspec tries the following

```
   [:==, :<, :<=, :>=, :>, :===].each do |operator|
      define_method operator do |operand|
        BeComparedTo.new(operand, operator)
      end
    end
```

Whereas, when you try `should.be_nil` it just checks

```
object.nil?
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/be.rb

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no difference but it's used for consistency with other methods like `be_true` or `be_false`.

Under the hood `be` checks the `id` of both elements:

- works with `nil`
- fails with `true` because in Ruby everything not `false` nor `nil` is `true`
- fails with `false` since both `nil` and `false` match