# Is this (Rspec example) a ruby code?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am learning Rspec.

I think Rspec codes are just ruby codes.
I found this code and it doesn't look like a correct ruby code.

```
37.should be < 100
```

If that's a ruby code, then 'be' should be a variable which is weird to me.
So it can be written like 37.should(be < 100).
What is it?

Sam

Comment: On second thought, 'be' could be a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`be` is a matcher that does some under-the-hood checks. The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856869/rspec-what-is-the-difference-between-be-nil-and-be-nil) question gives you some insight.

Also, looking at the [source](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/be.rb) for `be` is informative into how this is accomplished.

Comment: Rspec implements a DSL. `be` is not specifically standard Ruby, but implemented in it as this DSL. `be` is evaluated in the context of Rspec.

Comment: If you are interested in accomplishing this yourself or wanting more insight take a look [here](http://jroller.com/rolsen/entry/building_a_dsl_in_ruby).